# I am no longer able to use OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager OR PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, azure, sharepoint-app-registration

I usually run those command inside my CSOM code to authenticate to Office 365 using ClientId + ClientSecret:-

```
using (ClientContext context2 = new PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret, AzureEnvironment.Production))
```

&

```
using (ClientContext context3 = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret, AzureEnvironment.Production))
```

But starting from yesterday the above commands are raising these errors:-

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.RequestFailedException: Token request failed. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server
```

any advice? i checked the expiry date for the app and it is still valid till july 2021..